# How to create a cluster plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

How can I create a cluster plot in R without using [clustplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/clusplot.default.html)?

I am trying to get to grips with some clustering (using R) and visualisation (using HTML5 Canvas).

Basically, I want to create a [cluster plot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/clusplot.default.html) but instead of plotting the data, I want to get a set of 2D points or coordinates that I can pull into canvas and do something might pretty with (but I am unsure of how to do this). I would imagine that I:

1. Create a similarity matrix for the entire dataset (using dist)
2. Cluster the similarity matrix using kmeans or something similar (using kmeans)
3. Plot the result using MDS or PCA - but I am unsure of how steps 2 and 3 relate (cmdscale).

I've checked out questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084077/r-draw-kmeans-clustering-with-heatmap), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033594/how-to-create-a-clustergram-plot-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500193/should-one-use-distances-dissimilarities-or-similarities-in-r-for-clustering) (with the last one being of most use).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?
Sorry but i know nothing about HTML5 Canvas, only R... But I hope it helps...

First I cluster the data using kmeans (note that I did not cluster the distance matrix), than I compute the distance matix and plot it using cmdscale. Then I add colors to the MDS-plot that correspond to the groups identified by kmeans. Plus some nice additional graphical features.

You can access the coordinates from the object created by cmdscale.

```
### some sample data
require(vegan)
data(dune)

# kmeans
kclus <- kmeans(dune,centers= 4, iter.max=1000, nstart=10000)

# distance matrix
dune_dist <- dist(dune)

# Multidimensional scaling
cmd <- cmdscale(dune_dist)

# plot MDS, with colors by groups from kmeans
groups <- levels(factor(kclus$cluster))
ordiplot(cmd, type = "n")
cols <- c("steelblue", "darkred", "darkgreen", "pink")
for(i in seq_along(groups)){
  points(cmd[factor(kclus$cluster) == groups[i], ], col = cols[i], pch = 16)
}

# add spider and hull
ordispider(cmd, factor(kclus$cluster), label = TRUE)
ordihull(cmd, factor(kclus$cluster), lty = "dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @EDi, that is really great.  So, just to clarify, you cluster and then build a similarity matirx. You then use MDS to position the points in 2D and THEN you colour the points by their relationships to the cluster. Brilliant.  If you have a chance, could you explain what this does: groups <- levels(factor(kclus$cluster))

Comment: see my edit. groups is just an objekt that contains the names of the groups, only used for the for-loop.

Comment: Ok I see your edit.  One last question, can you cluster the distance matrix or is that a crazy move?  Sorry, learning at the moment and just working my way through things.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find one graph to analyze cluster results, "**coordinate plot**", within "clusplot" package.

It is not based on PCA. It uses function scale to have all the variables means in a range of 0 to 1, so you can compare which cluster holds the max/min average for each variable.

```
install.packages("devtools") ## To be able to download packages from github
library(devtools)
install_github("pablo14/clusplus")
library(clusplus)

## Create k-means model with 3 clusters
fit_mtcars=kmeans(mtcars,3)

## Call the function
plot_clus_coord(fit_mtcars, mtcars)
```

[This post](http://blog.datascienceheroes.com/short-lesson-on-cluster-analysis/) explains how to use it.