# How to plot clusters of kmeans in R and show centroids?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset that has 6497 instance, 12 attributes, and a class variable called q (quality). The class values can range from 3 to 9. The data can be downloaded in CSV format [from here](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/i2o6ywbdu2ws55k/wine_nocolor.csv)

I am doing k-means cluster on this dataset and would like to plot it. But there seems to be something wrong with the plots I'm generating because I don't think they are representing the clusters. The plot I'm trying to generate is referred from this SO answer [How to create a cluster plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019632/how-to-create-a-cluster-plot-in-r)

Here is what I'm doing

```
library(vegan)
winequality <- read.csv("wine_nocolor.csv")
express <- winequality[, c("fa", "va", "ca", "rs", "ch", "fsd", "tsd", "d", "p", "s", "a")]
rownames(express) <- winequality$id
str(express) #'data.frame': 6497 obs. of  11 variables
kclus <- kmeans(express,centers= 3, iter.max=1000, nstart=10000) #takes a bit of time
wine_dist <- dist(express)
cmd <- cmdscale(wine_dist) #takes bit of time
groups <- levels(factor(kclus$cluster))
ordiplot(cmd, type = "n") #shows warning that Species scores not available
cols <- c("steelblue", "darkred", "darkgreen")
for(i in seq_along(groups)){
    points(cmd[factor(kclus$cluster) == groups[i], ], col = cols[i], pch = 16)
}

# add spider and hull
ordispider(cmd, factor(kclus$cluster), label = TRUE)
ordihull(cmd, factor(kclus$cluster), lty = "dotted")
```

The above code produces the following plot. But as you can see, the clusters aren't demonstrated in a clear fashion.

[image]

**Questions**

- What are Dim1 and Dim2?
- How can I fix this?
- Additionally, does R offer a way to produce a plot similar to the plot generated by scikit for showing clusters and centroids?

Comment: you are creating a cluster over 11 variables, it is normal that on a 2 dimensional plot the clusters do not look separated. By the way I would try to reduce first the number of variables before applying the k-means. You might have much better results

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying. I still need to understand what Dim1 and Dim2 mean? and whether its possible to create plot similar to this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/plot_kmeans_digits_0011.png Here the class values could be from 1 to 10 and they chose 10 clusters

Comment: The data doesn't cluster - at least not with kmeans. **The ptroduced clusters are meaningless.** there is no separation or structure captured.

Comment: The tiles appear to be produced using a varonoi diagram, which is not clustering data _per se_.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse are you saying the wine data doesn't cluster??

Comment: Not with this projection/preprocessing/normalization. The clusters he got are meaningless; it's simply splitting the data into three *slices* based on the first principal component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of this code (from the other SO question) is using a dimension reduction using MDS (Multi Dimensional Scaling) to plot the cluster.

Read `?cmdscale` to understand.

Also some good sources [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) and [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2333639?sid=21105845590641&uid=4&uid=3738992&uid=2).

Whether you want to do this dimension reduction, and before or after the clustering, is your choice, I am not sure there is anything "to fix" in this code, it is more for you to decide what you want to do and plot.
I would suggest you try first to reduce the number of variables before the clustering. 11 is really a lot. Are they all useful?

Also remember that variables need to be normalized before applying the k-means.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not forget to preprocess your data carefully!**

In the image you showed above, the result was **completely dominated* by the `tsd` attribute. All other data was essentially not taken into account!**
(The `fsd` attribute had some minor effect, the others were dwarfed.)

The data set does not appear to cluster well.

This is the best result I could get:
[image]

One may argue that there are two types in this data set. But they are not well separated. It may as well be an oddly shaped *single* cluster.

In particular, the way the data is split changes a lot depending on how you preprocess and scale your data. That indicates the results are not stable.

Comment: I will be applying PCA and other data preprocessing techniques on this dataset now to see how it changes. Can you **please** share how you crated the above plot? So that I can plot it before and after my preprocessing techniques to see how it splits? Also, how did you determine that `tsd` attribute was overpowering the data. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use R, so I cannot share R code with you. I plotted the `tsd` attribute, and the k-means clusters would be orthogonal slices, as in your plot above.

Comment: Did you use matlab or scipy? I'm looking for a way to visually see how well the data splits before/after I apply preprocessing to it using PCA, ICA, etc. I don't mind switching tools to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: So, in the plot you created only the tsd attribute was taken into account?

Comment: No. But when I did *not* preprocess the data, and I chose x axis = tsd, it looked liked your plot, with the data being split according to the x axis.